# Using GUI causes "Sleep?" making Audio stutter/stop

Tags: user-interface, sleep, playback, lag

Okay, as Title says.

For example, i use NAudio to playback what i record (loopback if you want).

And if i click on the GUI (the top part, so i can move the window).
It will cause a "sleep", and when that happens the current activity (Audio playback) stops.
And then it continues afterwards.

But i want to remove that, as i don´t know any other application that has it, so it´s probably something to do with how i am programming.

Please keep it simple, i am extremely new to c#.

I am guessing on Bakckgroundworker or something, but i couldn´t get it to work.

So hopping for a more concrete answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was just me not understanding that using the Main Thread in a window form will cause anything on the GUI to be run on it.

Meaning, if i move the GUI, that movement will be Priority over the rest of the code, so everything else will get paused if run on that thread.

Perhaps it differ from object to object, but in this scenario it was the case, so i just moved it to a separate thread and it´s solved.